# For looping for write array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, reference

I want to know, Why this looping doesn't work properly? 
It's only displaying mhs3. 
I want to fix it, so it can display all of mhs.

```
        Mahasiswa mhs1 = new Mahasiswa();
        mhs1.Nim = "1234";
        mhs1.Nama = "Kelly";
        mhs1.Nilai = 95;

        Mahasiswa mhs2 = new Mahasiswa();
        mhs1.Nim = "1235";
        mhs1.Nama = "Bill";
        mhs1.Nilai = 80;

        Mahasiswa mhs3 = new Mahasiswa();
        mhs1.Nim = "1236";
        mhs1.Nama = "Saito";
        mhs1.Nilai = 92;

        //Mahasiswa Array Object Declaration
        Mahasiswa[] arrMahasiswa = new Mahasiswa[3];

        arrMahasiswa[0] = mhs1;
        arrMahasiswa[1] = mhs2;
        arrMahasiswa[2] = mhs3;

        Console.WriteLine("No. Nim        Nama          Nilai");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");

        for(int i=0; i<arrMahasiswa.Length; i++)
        {
            Mahasiswa mhs = arrMahasiswa[i];
            Console.WriteLine("{0}.  {1}        {2}         {3}", i+1, mhs.Nim, mhs.Nama, mhs.Nilai);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Look carefully at the statements under `Mahasiswa mhs2 = new Mahasiswa();`...

Comment: Consider using [object initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) to prevent these kinds of typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo

```
    Mahasiswa mhs2 = new Mahasiswa();
    mhs2.Nim = "1235";
    mhs2.Nama = "Bill";
    mhs2.Nilai = 80;

    Mahasiswa mhs3 = new Mahasiswa();
    mhs3.Nim = "1236";
    mhs3.Nama = "Saito";
    mhs3.Nilai = 92;
```

Comment: Hahaha, I forgot to change them. Thanks sir